# Python 2.7.13: RandomForestClassifier could not be imported from the other file

Tags: python, nlp, importerror, random-forest

in my project I am trying to separate different implemented classifiers in the separate files (in order to make code less messy).
Unfortunately, when I am importing file containing the RandomForestClassifier the program neither stops its execution nor shows an error, the code is provided here:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation 
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


def train_rfc(X,y):
    n_estimators = [100]
    min_samples_split = [2]
    min_samples_leaf = [1]
    bootstrap = [True]
    parameters = {'n_estimators': n_estimators, 'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
              'min_samples_split': min_samples_split}
    clf = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(verbose=1,n_jobs=-1), cv=4, param_grid=parameters)
    print "=="
    clf.fit(X, y)
    print "++"

    return clf


rfc_clf = train_rfc(corpus,data["target"])
print ("Accuracy of RF on CV sets :{}".format(rfc_clf.best_score_))
```

As I was able to figure out the problem is most likely to be somewhere in the RandomForest, and is in clf.fit(X,y) function to be exact, since the program does not do anything as soon as it reaches this point.
I had no problem running the other, similarly implemented SVM classifier that also used GridSearchCV, and was also inside of a function.

I would really appreciate any help on that.

Comment: I don't see that you are saving the model, and where are you loading the data and trying to load the model?

Comment: If you've trained your model in a different file you will need to persist it. see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html.
Or is this not what you're asking?

Comment: First try with `n_jobs=-1` to see if its working